# Building and verifying a tag system

Tags: php, mysql, keyword

I am creating a tag system similar to the one stack overflow uses and I need to check newly entered tags against the database of tags, and if it finds a match to use the key of the existing tag for connecting to the item. I am running into issues with this verification process. I am unsure of how to go about it. This is what I have so far.

```
$sql = $dbRead->quoteInto("SELECT * FROM item_tag WHERE tag IN (?)", $tag_where);

$tag_result = $dbRead->fetchAll($sql);

    $i = 0;
    while ($i < count($tags)) {

if (in_array($tags[$i], $tag_result)) {

    $array_key = array_search($tags[$i], $tag_result);

    }
else {
    $data = array ('tag' => $tags[$i]);
$dbWrite->insert('item_tag', $data);
$tag_ID = $dbWrite->lastInsertId();  }

$data = array('itemID' => $item_ID,
              'tagID'   => $tag_ID);
$dbWrite->insert('item_tag_connection', $data);
++$i;
    }
```

The problem is this part of the if else.

```
if (in_array($tags[$i], $tag_result)) {

    $array_key = array_search($tags[$i], $tag_result);

    }
```

I queried the tag table with an array filled with the tags the user entered. I packaged the results in an array with both the tag and the tags primary key. I then went about going through each user entered tag and checked it against the array. The part where I run into a problem is getting that primary key when I get a hit on a tag.

I am not set in doing it this particular way. If there is another method of achieving the same result that would be less convoluted, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a stored procedure and make a single call from my PHP code to MySQL. Unfortunately MySQL isn't great at handling array type params and doesnt support table return types so the stored procedure might look a little bit ugly :(

**Example call:**

```
-- usage: call insert_question(<user_id>,<question>,<tags>,<separator>);

call insert_question(1,'why are stored procs useful ?', 'database,mysql,stored-procedures,kiss,performance',',');

$sql = sprintf("call insert_question(%d,'%s','%s','%s')", $userID,$ques,$tags,$separator);
```

**Output:**

```
mysql> select * from tags order by tag_id;
+--------+-------------------+
| tag_id | tag               |
+--------+-------------------+
|      1 | database          |
|      2 | mysql             |
|      3 | stored-procedures |
+--------+-------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from questions order by question_id;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from question_tags order by tag_id, question_id;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

now we'll call the sproc:

```
call insert_question(1,'why are stored procs useful ?', 'database,mysql,stored-procedures,kiss,performance',',');

mysql> select * from tags order by tag_id;
+--------+-------------------+
| tag_id | tag               |
+--------+-------------------+
|      1 | database          |
|      2 | mysql             |
|      3 | stored-procedures |
|      4 | kiss              |
|      5 | performance       |
+--------+-------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from questions order by question_id;
+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+---------------------+
| question_id | user_id | question                      | created_date        |
+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+---------------------+
|           1 |       1 | why are stored procs useful ? | 2012-02-02 00:54:26 |
+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from question_tags order by tag_id, question_id;
+--------+-------------+
| tag_id | question_id |
+--------+-------------+
|      1 |           1 |
|      2 |           1 |
|      3 |           1 |
|      4 |           1 |
|      5 |           1 |
+--------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Script:**

full script here: http://pastie.org/3299425

```
-- TABLES

drop table if exists users;
create table users
(
user_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
username varchar(32) unique not null
)
engine=innodb;

drop table if exists tags;
create table tags
(
tag_id smallint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
tag varchar(255) unique not null
)
engine=innodb;

drop table if exists questions;
create table questions
(
question_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
user_id int unsigned not null,
question varchar(512) not null,
created_date datetime not null
)
engine=innodb;

drop table if exists question_tags;
create table question_tags
(
tag_id smallint unsigned not null,
question_id int unsigned not null,
primary key (tag_id, question_id) -- clustered composite pk
)
engine=innodb;

-- PROCS

drop procedure if exists insert_question;

delimiter #
create procedure insert_question
(
in p_user_id int unsigned,
in p_question varchar(512),
in p_tags_csv mediumtext, -- comma separated plz
in p_separator char(1)
)
/*
usage:
call insert_question(1,'why are stored procs useful ?', 'database,mysql,stored-procedures,kiss,performance',',');

$sql = sprintf("call insert_question(%d,'%s','%s','%s)", $userID,$ques,$tags,$separator);

*/

proc_main:begin

declare v_question_id int unsigned default 0;
declare v_done tinyint unsigned default 0;
declare v_idx int unsigned default 1;
declare v_tag varchar(255) default null;

-- validate input params

if p_separator is null or length(p_separator) <= 0 then 
  set p_separator = ',';
end if;
if p_question is null or length(p_question) <= 0 then 
  leave proc_main;
end if;
if p_tags_csv is null or length(p_tags_csv) <= 0 then 
  leave proc_main;
end if;

-- split the tags into a memory table (ugly bit as mysql doesnt support table types)

drop temporary table if exists tmp_tags;

create temporary table tmp_tags(
 tag_id smallint unsigned null,
 tag varchar(255)
)engine = memory;   

while not v_done do

  set v_tag = trim(substring(p_tags_csv, v_idx, 
    if(locate(p_separator, p_tags_csv, v_idx) > 0, 
       locate(p_separator, p_tags_csv, v_idx) - v_idx, length(p_tags_csv))));

  if length(v_tag) > 0 then
    set v_idx = v_idx + length(v_tag) + 1;
    insert into tmp_tags(tag) values(v_tag);
  else
    set v_done = 1;
  end if;
end while;

-- which tags do we already have ?

update tmp_tags tt
inner join tags t on t.tag = tt.tag
set tt.tag_id = t.tag_id;

-- insert tags

insert into tags (tag) select tag from tmp_tags where tag_id is null;

update tmp_tags tt
inner join tags t on t.tag = tt.tag
set tt.tag_id = t.tag_id
where
 tt.tag_id is null;

-- insert question and question_tags

insert into questions (user_id, question, created_date) values (p_user_id, p_question, now());

set v_question_id = last_insert_id();

insert into question_tags 
select distinct tag_id, v_question_id from tmp_tags;

-- return output

select 
 p_question,
 u.user_id,
 u.username,
 v_question_id, 
 tt.* 
from 
 tmp_tags tt
inner join users u on u.user_id = p_user_id
order by
 tt.tag_id;

-- cleanup

drop temporary table if exists tmp_tags;

end proc_main #

delimiter ;

-- TEST DATA

insert into users (username) values ('f00');
insert into tags (tag) values ('database'),('mysql'),('stored-procedures');

-- TESTING

select * from users order by user_id;
select * from tags order by tag_id;
select * from questions order by question_id;
select * from question_tags order by tag_id, question_id;

call insert_question(1,'why are stored procs useful ?', 'database,mysql,stored-procedures,kiss,performance',',');

select * from tags order by tag_id;
select * from questions order by question_id;
select * from question_tags order by tag_id, question_id;
```

Hope this helps :)

**Edit:**

ofc, in any other RDBMS (sql server, oracle) the sproc would be trivial:)

Comment: Wow, good work. Maybe a little over-complicated for this system, but any extra exposure for stored procedures is a good thing. So many systems seem to ignore them, making any complex work difficult.

Comment: Unfortunately it's MySQL that makes this server side solution complex. SQL server for example has table types etc that would simplify the sproc to a couple of statements - but thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It is the way you are using the array `$tag_result`. Mind you that `$tag_result` is not an array of tags, but it is an array of a rows. Each row contais, as far as i can tell from your code, a `tagID` and `tag`. So your `$tag_result` array will look something like:

```
$tag_result = [ {tagID: 1, tag: "php"} , {tagID: 2, tag: "mysql"}, {tagID: 3, tag: "tags"} ]
```

The best way to do this is, instead of asking all the tags from the database (which is very very inefficient) you query something like this:

```
$sql = $dbRead->quoteInto("SELECT * FROM item_tag WHERE tag IN (?)", "'" . join("','", $tags) . "'" );
```